# Eisenstein's Criterion proof

Tags: ring-theory, proof-explanation

In the attached image, the proof is almost clear to me except the fact that: " Supoose that $p \vert b_i$
for $i$ in the range $0\le i \le i_1$, and $p$ does not divide $b_{i_1}$. There is such an index $i_1$ since $g$ is monic."

Can someone please explain why such an index $i_1$ exists even if $g$ is monic, i mean what does it have to do with the fact that $g$ is monic? This part of the proof is unclear to me, if someone can explain me this, it would be really helpful. Thanks.
[image: Proof of Eisenstein's Criterion]

Comment: There seems to be a mistake in the text. I think it should say "for $i$ in the range $0 \leq i < i_1$". Otherwise, it implies both $p|b_{i_1}$ and $p \not| b_{i_1}$.

Comment: @aschepler yeah that's okay. One can understand that, but my doubt was different.

Answer (score 1):

We have
$$
g(x)=b_mx^m +b_{m-1}x^{m-1}+\cdots +b_1x+b_0
$$
We know (or rather, assume) that $p\mid b_0$, and $g$ being monic means we know that $p\nmid b_m$ (since $b_m=1$). Thus there must be a *first* index $i_1$ such that $p\nmid b_{i_1}$, and we know $i_1>0$.

As pointed out in a comment above, there is a typo, and probably it should be $0\leq i<i_1$.